# resp.encodeRedirectUrl("url") не перенаправляет запрос на другой сервлет

Tags: java, jsp, servlet

проходя по ссылке http://localhost:8080/login.html, попадаю на страницу сервелета Login  . Этот сервлет перенаправляет нас на другой сервлет list, доступный по адресу: http://localhost:8080/list

Код сервлета логин ниже:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String name = req.getParameter("name");
    if (name == null || name.equals("")) {
        req.getSession().setAttribute("userName", "anonimous");
    } else {
        req.getSession().setAttribute("userName", name);
    }

    **resp.sendRedirect("http://localhost:8080/list");**
}
```

После того, как меняю строку на resp.encodeRedirectUrl("http://localhost:8080/list") , сервлет  перестает работать должным образом, пересылая меня вместо http://localhost:8080/list на http://localhost:8080/login?name=testName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может я не совсем правильно понял Ваш вопрос, но метод **resp.encodeRedirectUrl()** и не должен вас перенаправлять на сервлет "list". Этот метод не выполняет перенаправление - он просто кодирует URL, и добавляет в него ID сессии, если на клиенте ( браузере) отключены Cookies.
Обратите внимание - метод **resp.encodeRedirectUrl()** возвращает вам строку - эта строка - это и есть закодированный URL, который вы должны передать в метод sendRedirect().

Также, попробуйте отключить в браузере Куки - увидите, что в Ваш, URL добавится ID сессии - это и есть результат работы метода encodeRedirectUrl().

Уточняйте, если что-то недорассказал.

Comment: Большое спасибо! Теперь понял